# Find all Javascript instances from a page

Tags: jquery, dom, javascript

If I have some javascript classes and instances defined in a HTML page.
How can I get the names of those instances ?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Vehicle(hasEngine, hasWheels) {
            this.hasEngine = hasEngine || false;
                this.hasWheels = hasWheels || false;
        }

        function Car (make, model, hp) {        
            this.hp = hp;
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
        }

        var car1 = new Car();
        var v1 = new Vehicle();
    </script>
</body></html>
```

Is there a javascript library to do this ?

I want to get all the instances and names of the classes to generate a UML class diagram from from the static object defined in the page.

Practicaly the same thing that the Firebug Console does when you write the name of a instance. He automaticaly knows all the instances in the page and all its methods.
Not the objects defined in the Console, at the runtime.

Comment: Most of the time when you need to programatically get the name of a function / class, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Potentially you mean this from a testing/documentation perspective? qUnit etc will do this.

Comment: I want to get all the instances and names of the classes to generate a UML class diagram from that.

Comment: @GeorgesC What do you want to get? `Car` and `Vehicule` or `car1` and `v1`?

Comment: You want static code analysis. You don't generate UML diagrams from running instances of your program, you generate them from the source code.

Comment: Yes I want to read the static code. Sorry for not explaning very good my question. 
How can I read the static instances defined in the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be much better to do it like this?

```
function Car (name /*, other variables */) {

   this.Name = name;
   // other properties

}

var car1 = new Car("car1");
console.log(car1.Name);
```

The variable name is something you should know inside of your code. If you don't, you're clearly doing something wrong.

As far as I know, you can only get `Car`, `Vehicle` and their properties name (`hp`, `make`, `model`).

```
for (var i in car1) {

  if (car1.hasOwnProperty(i))
   console.log(car1[i]);

}
```

will give you

```
hp
make
model
```

and

```
car1.constructor.name
```

will give you

```
Car
```

---

> knows all the instances in the page

if you want to get all the instances of `Car` you'll have to **store them in an array** (which is the best approach) or, in alternative, you can get them by yourself by iterating over all the variables in the page (which is horrible).

```
for (var i in window) {
   if (window[i].constructor.name == "Car") {
      console.log(window[i]) // -> here you'll have the object
      console.log(i) // -> here you'll have the variable name
   }
```

> and all its methods

methods of an object should be stored in its prototype, depending on how you constructed your class.

`car1.prototype` contains the methods declared in the prototype of `Car`.

An alternative approach, for methods which are not in the prototype, is this (which is horrible, again):

```
for (var i in car1) {

  if (car1.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof(car1[i]) == 'function')
   console.log(car1[i]);

}
```

Comment: I want to get all the instances and names of the classes to generate a UML class diagram from that.
Practicaly the same thing the Console from Firebug does.

Comment: thank you @Saturnix. 
But how can I know that the object car1 is instantiated in that page ?

Comment: Please don't use the crappy code I've written. Just store your instances in an array, it is much better.

Comment: But it is good I actualy do 
if(typeof(window[i]) == "object")
I get all the objects in the page, then when I got the names I search if they are instantiated and next search for the UML relations betwen the objects to create the diagrams. It is good, thank you. 
I don't think there is another solution

Comment: please note that with what you're doing won't be getting nested objects. For example, if window[i] is an object (for example, "Car") and inside of this object you have another object (for example, "Seat" or "Wheel") you won't be getting the latter. You should write a recursive function to do this. for(var i in object) is what you should do inside of such a function, if you'll ever need it.

Answer (score 0):

This would require changes to your class definitions, but you could have each class register itself:

```
function Vehicle(...) {
    ...

    this.constructor.instances.push(this);
}

Vehicle.instances = [];

function Car(...) {
    ...

    this.constructor.instances.push(this);
}

Car.instances = [];
```

Then at least you can loop through Vehicle.instances and Car.instances. As @Saturnix mentioned, the `constructor.name` property of each instance will give you the name of the constructor function:

```
var i = 0, length = Car.instances.length, instance

for (i; i < length; i++) {
    instance = Car.instances[i];
    console.log(instance.constructor.name + " [" + i + "]", instance);
}
```